# Click en recyclerview no funciona y no da error

Tags: java, android

Estoy en pleno desarrollo de una aplicación, uso fragments y uno de ellos cargo un layout con un `RecyclerView`, al principio el click y long click se realizaban, no me da ningún error, ya que la aplicación funciona perfectamente pero no lanza los eventos (no uso control de versiones) por eso me pregunto que causas podría afectar que dejase de funcionar.

Añado el código del adaptador del `RecyclerView`:

```
    public class AdaptadorListaSenderos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorListaSenderos.ViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = "AdaptadorListaSenderos";
private Context context;

//List of senderos
List<Sendero> senderos;

public AdaptadorListaSenderos(List<Sendero> senderos, Context context){
    super();
    //Getting all the senderos
    this.senderos = senderos;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_item_footpaths, parent, false);
    final ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int position = vh.getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                Toast.makeText(context, Integer.toString(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.v(TAG, "onClick() position with: " + position);
            }
        }

    });
    v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            final int position = vh.getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                Toast.makeText(context, Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "onLongClick() position with:" + position);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    return vh;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Sendero row =  senderos.get(position);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(row.getCoverImage(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.default_image, R.drawable.error_image));

    holder.imageView.setImageUrl(row.getCoverImage(), imageLoader);
    holder.textViewName.setText(row.getTitle());
    holder.textViewAge.setText(row.getExcerpt());
    //holder.currentItem = position;
    holder.currentItem = senderos.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return senderos.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public View view;
    public Sendero currentItem;

    public NetworkImageView imageView;
    public TextView textViewName;
    public TextView textViewAge;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        view = v;
        imageView = (NetworkImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cover_image);
        textViewName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        textViewAge= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.edad);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: creo que ayudaria que pusieras algo de codigo para que podamos ver como se esta usando Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por fin lo he solucionado,el problema era en la definición del layout tenia el control que englobaba los componentes con la propiedad `android:clickable="true"` y eso hacia no delegar el touch hacia el adaptador.

Comment: No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta si es la solución.

Comment: Me dice que tengo que esperar 2 dias

Comment: Es así, solo para que no lo olvides. que bueno que pudiste solucionarlo.