# ¿Cómo llamar una Activity desde un RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, xml

Tengo un problema para llamar a una `Activity`, desde un `ImageButton` que está dentro de una `CardView` y ésta está dentro de un `RecyclerView`, y el `RecyclerView` está dentro de un tab de un fragmento. Lo que intenté como en otros casos es poner algo así:

`ImageButton` >> `cardview` >> `recyclerview` >> `tab`.

```
public void callBreakFast(){
    imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbt1);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActividadOrigen.this, ActividadDestino.class);
          startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Pero no me funciona el código.

Mi fragmento `FragEatingTabToday.java` que es un tab que contiene una lista de items:

```
public class FragEatingTabToday extends Fragment {

  private LinearLayoutManager linearLayout;
  private ImageButton imageButton;

  public FragEatingTabToday() { }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento_yesterday, container, false);

    RecyclerView reciclador = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    linearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    reciclador.setLayoutManager(linearLayout);

    AdapEatingToday adaptador = new AdapEatingToday(ModelEating.ACTIVIDADES);

    reciclador.setAdapter(adaptador);
    return view;
  }
}
```

Y su respectivo `XML` llamado `fragmento_yesterday.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

El otro archivo adaptador `AdapEatingToday.java`:

```
public class AdapEatingToday extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapEatingToday.ViewHolder> {

  private final List<ModelEating> items;

  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView titulo;
    public TextView horario;
    public ImageButton picture;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
      super(v);
      titulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.texto_titulo);
      horario = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.texto_horario);
      picture = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbt1);
    }
  }

  public AdapEatingToday(List<ModelEating> items) {
    this.items = items;
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
  }

  @Override
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_lista_yesterday, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    ModelEating item = items.get(i);
    viewHolder.titulo.setText(item.getActividad());
    viewHolder.horario.setText(item.getHora());
  }
}
```

Y el XML `item_lista_yesterday.xml` de los items que es un `CardView` que contiene `TextView` e `ImageButton`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="#C5CAE9"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="6dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/texto_titulo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:text="texto1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/texto_horario"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/texto_titulo"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="texto2"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/linea_divisora1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#bebebe" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgbt1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@mipmap/bread"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/linea_divisora2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="#bebebe" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Mirate el código de la siguiente entrada http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2242/click-en-recyclerview-no-funciona-y-no-da-error hay como usar los eventos click dentro de un recyclerview

Comment: pudiste ya solucionar la cuestión?

Comment: Aqui hay un ejemplo oficial de Google https://developer.android.com/samples/RecyclerView/src/com.example.android.recyclerview/CustomAdapter.html

Answer (score 2):

Dentro de un Fragment para referirte al contexto de cualquier cosa tienes que usar algo como `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` ya que en si el Fragmento no es una actividad.
Por ejemplo:

```
AdapEatingToday adaptador = new AdapEatingToday(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),datos);
```

datos serian los datos a cargar en el adaptador pero esto es lateral al comentario anterior.

Answer (score 0):

En tu adapter del `RecyclerView`, necesitas poner algo como esto:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    private String mItem;
    private TextView mTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTextView = (TextView) view;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        mItem = item;
        mTextView.setText(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick " + getPosition() + " " + mItem);
    }
}
```

Ya no existe el `onClickItem` o algo parecido.

Answer (score 0):

No se porque ahora es tan complicado pero yo cuando lo hice, lo hice mas o menos asi.

```
public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView imgView;
   /// un listener para recuperar un el touch espesifico sobre uno de los  items del cardview
    // y a cada uno de los views se les agrega el listenre para que escuchen el click
    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imgView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgGeneral_gab);
        imgView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         if (v.getId() == R.id.imgGeneral_gab) {
            mListener.onImageClick(v, getPosition());
        }
    }
}

public interface IMyViewHolderClicks {
    void onImageClick(View v, int position);
}
```

Y en el adapter RecyclerView.Adapter addListener obviamente.

```
 public void addOnViewsListener(IMyViewHolderClicks listener){
    mListener = listener;
}
```

Y al final en el Fragment.

```
    AdapEatingToday adaptador = new AdapEatingToday(ModelEating.ACTIVIDADES);
    adaptador.addOnViewsListener(new MainAdapter.IMyViewHolderClicks() {

        @Override
        public void onImageClick(View v, int position) {
          // AQUI SUCEDE LA MAGIA
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con ese código

```
public class AdapEatingToday extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapEatingToday.ViewHolder> {

  private final List<ModelEating> items;

  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView titulo;
    public TextView horario;
    public ImageButton picture;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
      super(v);
      titulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.texto_titulo);
      horario = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.texto_horario);
      picture = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbt1);
    }
  }

  public AdapEatingToday(List<ModelEating> items) {
    this.items = items;
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
  }

  @Override
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_lista_yesterday, viewGroup, false);


    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //lanzar activity
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActividadOrigen.this, ActividadDestino.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }

    });


    return new ViewHolder(v);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    ModelEating item = items.get(i);
    viewHolder.titulo.setText(item.getActividad());
    viewHolder.horario.setText(item.getHora());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla es agregando un `OnItemClickListener` al Adapter:

```
Adapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View v , int position) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActividadOrigen.this, ActividadDestino.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Podrías también dependiendo de la posición del elemento en el `Adapter`,  abrir diferentes actividades, por ejemplo :

```
Adapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View v , int position) {

    Intent myIntent;
    switch(position){
        case 0:
          myIntent = new Intent(ActividadOrigen.this, ActividadDestinoA.class);             
        break;
        case 1:
          myIntent = new Intent(ActividadOrigen.this, ActividadDestinoB.class);             
        break;
        case 2:
          myIntent = new Intent(ActividadOrigen.this, ActividadDestinoC.class);             
        break;  
    }
    startActivity(myIntent);

    }
});
```