# Crear una vista en detalle de una cardview seleccionada en un recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview

He seguido [este tutorial](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-cardview/) para crear una lista de cardviews y ahora me gustaría que después de hacer click en una cardview se inicie una activity nueva "cardview_detalle" en la cual mostrar la información detallada de la cardview seleccionada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro del adaptador del `RecyclerView` pon el código para lanzar la `activity`

```
private final Context context;
...
    public ViewHolder (View v) {
        super(v);
        context = v.getContext();
        ...
    }
```

Y en el evento `onClick()`

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, cardview_detalle.class));
```

Comment: ¿cómo podría obtener la id de la cardview en la que el usuario hace click para saber que información he de cargar?

Comment: @Mihawk mirate http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2242/click-en-recyclerview-no-funciona-y-no-da-error

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda